# WSO2 CONTENT_TYPE="text/plain" no use?

Tags: properties, wso2, esb

In the document, property CONTENT_TYPE is :

```
In situations where the ESB is receiving HTTP response messages without the Content-type header, this property can be used to specify a default content type to be used. If no such content type is specified for responses the ESB will default to 'application/octet-stream'.
```

I have a HTTP test service response messages without the Content-type, so I set property CONTENT_TYPE="text/plain" in ESB config. The response is:

```
<axis2ns3:binary xmlns:axis2ns3="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">UmV0dXJuQ29kZT0wMDAwMDANCg==</axis2ns3:binary>
```

If I add `resp.setContentType("text/plain")` in my HTTP test service,the response is:

```
<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">ReturnCode=000000</text>
```

Seems property CONTENT_TYPE setting above is no use, is still default to 'application/octet-stream'.

I have a HTTP service without Content-type header,and then response message is binary. How to set response CONTENT_TYPE="text/plain"? Anyone can help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: Can you post your ESB configuration which you used to set the content-type?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the messageFormatters in the axis2.xml ($ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml)

```
<messageFormatter contentType="text/plain" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>
```

Then you can change the content-type using the property mediator as follows:

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"/>
```